# css responsivness, if one element "touches" other element change css position

Tags: css, responsive-design

how can I change the position of an element when one touches the other.

here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/mZYR8/1/

so if you look at the example lets say if .title-wrap (yellow) touches .right-wrap (orange) I would like orange to "go" undenith yellow

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="title-wrap">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right-wrap">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .title-wrap {
        background-color:yellow;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    h1 {

        font-size:20px;
        line-height:40px;
    }
    .right-wrap {
        position:absolute;
        display:inline-block;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
        background-color:orange;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .right-wrap span {
        display:inline-block;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        margin-right:10px;
        background-color:purple;
    }
</style>
```

**from here UPDATED the Question cause "yellow undenith" was not clear**

so if one element touches the other I would like to change

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
```

to position:relative; and it shoudl look like this:

[image: how it should look with position:relative;]

I can change what ever is needed and could also add javascript. but if possible with css only I would like it with css.

thanks for helping!

Comment: You need to look into media queries and breakpoints. No JS is really needed.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I tried with media queries but I don't know the width of div.title-wrap and also I don't know the width of div.right-wrap cause this can be loaded dynamically.

Comment: Width is set in the media queries...that's the point.

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought media queries only work with screen width (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen) show me how to use it with <div> width and you are my hero

Comment: @Paulie_D Media queries are very good, but I think it is also worth pointing out that they don't work without extra help in IE8 and below. So you should carefully look at your target audience before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got a solution, which is to float the element to the right.

If anyone knows a better solution, please feel free to add an answer.

This seems to work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/mZYR8/2/

```
   .right-wrap {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        right:0px;
        top:0px;
        background-color:orange;
        padding:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make an element appear above another by giving them the `z-index` CSS property.

```
.right-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    background-color:orange;
    padding:20px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

And:

```
.title-wrap {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}
```

should work (the higher `z-index` goes on top)

Comment: ou thank you, with on top I mean position:relative; hold on I'll add a picture to the question

Comment: @caramba Ah okay, I misunderstood. I'll leave this answer here for now and look into answering your actual question.

Comment: thanks for helping, I've got an answer, what do you think. It is what I want, any reasons to not use float right?

Comment: @caramba There is no reason to not use `float:right` that I know of, good on you that you found the solution that suits your needs!