# Media Queries for Elements

Tags: css

Media Queries for HTMl Elements. For example :

```css
.container(min-width: 500px)
 {
  .wid-sm {width: 200px;}
 }
```

I want to make the element responsive like Media Queries. kindly provide me the solution.

Comment: Asked and answered more than once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the css for different resolution like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

   .wid-sm {width: 200px;}

}
@media (min-width: 600px and max-width: 800) {

   .wid-sm {width: 350px;}

}
```

Comment: This is not the question.

Comment: First you want to get the container size then accordingly resize the wid-sm div. Is this what you want?

Comment: He wants to specify a media query-*like* rule, but basing it on the size of an element rather than on the size of the screen, a feature which of course is not in CSS.