# How can I make Bootstrap function only inside a Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement that needs all of Bootstrap's responsiveness to appear in a subsection of the page. I need an area to be static for existing content, and the remaining area for Twitter Bootstrap to do its resize magic. I can't seem to get this to work with just a sub-div, and am close to depending on an iFrame for the right side SPA that will exist.

[image]

Readjusting the image queries doesn't seem to be enough for this case. Anyone have any ideas or solutions to this?

Edit:
I forgot to include - we need to have the responsive behavior actually respond to **the size of the div element, rather than the browser size**. That means that the media queries of bootstrap will pay attention to what the div size is rather than the window size. I know that bootstrap is pretty tightly coupled with using media queries to determine the device size. How could we get this to happen?

[image]

Comment: You may want to check this sample template from their docs: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: This was an answer to a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the static width area `position:fixed`, and then offset the right panel by the width of the static area.

Bootstrap provides [an example of exactly this use case](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/).

Comment: I forgot to mention a pretty important justification as to why that better explains the problem. I added it to the post... Do you have any ideas how something like mentioned could be achieved??