# Wrap when the browser width is too short to have everything inline

Tags: css

I'm designing a simple top-menu with a logo on the left, and inline-links on the right:

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#header { background-color: grey; }
#right { background-color: blue; float:right; }
#left { background-color: green; float:left; }
li { display:inline-block; padding: 0 30px; }
```

```html
 <div id="header">
   <div id="left">LOGOLOGOLOGOLOGOLOGOLOGO</div> 
   <div id="right">
     <ul>
       <li>Link 1</li>
       <li>Link 2</li>
       <li>Link 3</li>
       <li>Link 4</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I would like that :

- **when the browser width is enough for everything to be inline**, the links-list should be aligned on the right (`float: right`)
- **when the browser width is not enough for everything to be inline**, the links-list should be aligned on the left

[image]

How to do it with my code mentioned before?

---

*Note: I would like the "wrap effect" to appear **exactly** when*

```
width(#left)+width(#right)>width(browser)
```

*and **not** with something static like `width(browser)<300px`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( window ).resize(function(){
var lwidth=parseInt($('#left').css('width'));
var rwidth=parseInt($('#right').css('width'));
var fwidth=lwidth+rwidth;
var swidth=$(window).width()
if (fwidth > swidth){
    $('#right').css('float','left');}
else{$('#right').css('float','right');;}
});
 
});
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#header { background-color: grey; }
#right { background-color: blue; float:right; }
#left { background-color: green; float:left; }
li { display:inline-block; padding: 0 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
   <div id="left">LOGOLOGOLOGOLOGOLOGOLOGO</div> 
   <div id="right">
     <ul>
       <li>Link 1</li>
       <li>Link 2</li>
       <li>Link 3</li>
       <li>Link 4</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

check on load, if `width(#left)+width(#right)>width(browser)` then change `div#right` `float` from `right` to `left`.

```
     $( window ).resize(function(){
    var lwidth=parseInt($('#left').css('width'));
    var rwidth=parseInt($('#right').css('width'));
    var fwidth=lwidth+rwidth;
    var swidth=$(window).width()
    if (fwidth > swidth){
        $('#right').css('float','left');}
else{$('#right').css('float','right');;}
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to check this on `load` only, but on load + whenever the browser width changes

Comment: use window.resize() function.check the updated code.

Comment: Place this code in a function and then have: `$(window).resize(functionName)` as well as `functionName()`. This will ensure it runs on startup and on resize.

Comment: added else case too.to get back to float:right for div#right.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries [don't support individual elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen) yet, so you're going to have to use Javascript to do this.

I would suggest using [css-element-queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries).  It allows you to write element based media queries so you don't have to write any javascript.

If you want to do it yourself, when the doc has loaded, use something like

```
  if (document.getElementById('left').offsetWidth + document.getElementById('right').offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) {
      //apply styles using javascript
  }
```

To do this when the window resizes:

```
  window.onresize = function(event) {
      if (document.getElementById('left').offsetWidth + document.getElementById('right').offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) {
        //apply styles using javascript
      }
  };
```

Comment: I used media queries before, but here I would like the wrap to appear **exactly** when   `width(#left)+width(#right)>width(browser)`  and **not** with something static like `300px`. How to do that?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use javascript to do this.

Comment: Are you sure @JPDurham ? I hoped there would be a way without JS

Comment: I wanted to find a solution for the top-menu of http://www.samplerbox.org when we resize the browser width. Any idea @JPDurham?

Comment: You could try using [a library to simulate this](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries).  You'll be able to use css, although it does use javascript to achieve this.

Comment: @Basj did either of the suggestions in my answer work for you or are you still looking for another solution?