# Making three-column HTML responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My page width is 960px and I have 3 divs on it in a horizontal manner that collectively take 100% of the width.

When the page width is decreased, I want the divs to be arranged in a vertical manner.

How can I do it in CSS ??

[image]

Comment: Use media screen rule property of CSS [For More](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Can you show the current HTML/CSS you're using for this?

Comment: I have answered similar kind of question.
Have a look at it.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190626/wrap-when-the-browser-width-is-too-short-to-have-everything-inline/30191089#30191089

Comment: I agree with @media rules, it's the easiest and most professional way, no JavaScript required. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css you can make use of media rules. For example, you can set new CSS styles, if the screen size goes below a certain width. In the case below it's set to use the new css rules once the width goes below 960px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .test-div {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

here is a full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pckphv38/

simply resize your browser and see.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

This will create a row with three equal size responsive columns..

Comment: You need to change the class to col-md-4, because the way it currently is shown will actually split it into 3 columns on mobile as well as desktop which is not what was requested in the OP

Comment: I un-downvoted because this guy/gal really should be using bootstrap for this

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/odou6pr1/)

One simple way of doing it is to toggle the float property using a media query. For body width > 960px, have them float left. Otherwise, let them line up normally as blocks.

```css
div {
  width: 33.3333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  div {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div> <span></span>

</div>
<div><span></span>

</div>
<div><span></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

create the div for these 3 divs
set the width to 100%
use `float: left;`
and `position:relative;` in the css

or you can use bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, apply the same `class` to all the divisions.

```
<div class="nm">
```

Then, from [How to get browser width using javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/), get the width of the screen with

```
function getWidth() {
  if (self.innerHeight) {
    return self.innerWidth;
  }

  if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  }

  if (document.body) {
    return document.body.clientWidth;
  }
}
```

And then change it depending on the width.

```
var value = 400;
if(getWidth() < value){
  var foo = document.getElementByClassName("nm");
  for(var i=0, j=foo.length; i<j; i++){
    foo[i].style.float = "none";
  }
}
```

To break it down:

1. Have a function get the width of the screen
2. Run through each element that needs to be changed
3. Change the CSS to remove the horizontal alignment.

Additionally, if you want to change it whenever the user stretches or pulls the browser, you can create a `setInterval` loop.

```
function doInterval(){
    var value = 400;
    if(getWidth() < value){
      var foo = document.getElementByClassName("nm");
      for(var i=0, j=foo.length; i<j; i++){
        foo[i].style.float = "none";
      }
    }
}

intv = setInterval(doInterval, 250);
```

Comment: Way too complex. You can simply use css @media rule to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

Way to arrange the elements in CSS3

(no effect in IE10 and earlier versions)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>demo</title>

        <style type='text/css'>
           #ctr {
              display: -webkit-flex;
              -webkit-flex-direction: column;
               display: flex;
               flex-direction: column;
            }

            .item {
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:pink;
                margin:2px;
            }

            @media (min-width: 960px) {
                #ctr {
                    display: -webkit-flex;
                    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                }
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="ctr">
        <div class="item">a</div>
        <div class="item">b</div>
        <div class="item">c</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are planning to use for multiple section, please use `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap960{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 31%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    min-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .box{
        display: block;
        margin: 1% auto 0 auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap960">
    <div class="box">box1</div>
    <div class="box">box2</div>
    <div class="box">box3</div>
</div>
```