# When CSS will include media queries which can apply to single elements?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, w3c

This question is about to define media queries for concrete DOM elements and not for the entire screen.

I know this question about media queries for elements (container elements) was treated here.
[Can media queries resize based on a div element instead of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen)

**But my question is if anyone knows if CSS (The W3C) will include specifications (and when, of course)**, because in my opinion it's a real need. without having to add javascript, plugins, etc like here had already commented.

As you probably know there are often situations where a container element which increases and then decreases and so on, according to the screen resolution changes, and thus this affects the items which it contains.

Common situation, for example: Consider a page that has a central and columns at the sides. According It decreases the overall resolution of the display a column is removed., this causes the size of the central content increases its size. The information blocks of the central part decreases and grow in size multiple times. It's a pain to have to include lots of media queries that apply to the screen to solve this. when the syntax specifications must focus on each container and not in the screen.

And it is very common to find several times on each project.

Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about "Content based media queries". read this [post](https://responsivedesign.is/articles/why-you-dont-need-device-specific-breakpoints)

Comment: I am interested in knowing about the future of CSS specifications, concretely for media queries applied to the page elements (and not to the screen). It is important for see how to plan the future.
Thank you.

Comment: I understand your concern but still to change the layout of an element you should definitely depend on view port size, that is what the above article explains. that is how content based media queries can be managed.BTW, this is just my opinion.

Comment: There's no possible answer to this question unless we can get the input of the W3 CSS Group...and that's not going to happen. The OP isn't going to find what they are looking for here. I'd suggest following the draft specs on the appropriate site.