# How can I hide a column when its width will be less than a certain size in CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to CSS grid and am not sure whether it is possible to accomplish the following without resorting to using JavaScript.

I am trying to hide a sidebar when it will be less than `200px` wide.

But I only want to show a sidebar when `200px` is no more than `40%` of the available width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 200px) 1fr 0; /* what goes here ? */
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grid .sidebar {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 1;
  background: red;
}

.grid .main {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

For instance, let's say `.grid` is `400px` wide. Then `40%` of `400px` is `160px`, but `200px` is more than `160px`, so `.sidebar` should either not display or have `0` width.

But if `.grid` is `1000px` wide, then `40%` of `1000px` is `400px`. Since `200px` is less than `400px`, it should display with width of `400px`.

Is this possible to do with just CSS grid, a combination of CSS grid and other CSS directives, or not possible without JavaScript?

Comment: You can use a media query, but it'd be based on the width of the page, not the grid/div.

Comment: I need it to respond to the container unfortunately, because this `div` could be in a big page but in a small container

Comment: Hmm... then I dunno. There's been [some talk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12251750/65387) but nothing implemented. Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: See: [Can media queries resize based on a div element instead of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen)

Comment: @mpen, thanks for the link to the JS library for Element Queries

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2b6cf4kw/1/ If this is what you're after. The only requirement: no margin for the parent container/wrapper when being resized from its defined max-width of the page down, i.e. needs to take full screen width, or at least when the .sidebar is closing to its min-width of 200px.

Comment: @VXp, hey thats awesome, can you put it in an answer?

Comment: @VXp actually, I spoke too soon... it looks like it works on JSFiddle because the page is framed, but actually, when you constrain the container to a small width, the sidebar still shows up

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, if I understand you correctly and this is what you are after:

```css
body {margin: 0} /* recommended */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 40%) 1fr; /* first column no more than 40%, ever (from 500px up) */
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grid .sidebar {
  /*grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 1;*/
  background: red;
}

.grid .main {
  /*grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;*/
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 499.99px) { /* screen width (or the .grid) needs to be at least 500px wide, in order to display the .sidebar, because min-width of 200px is exactly 40% of 500px, so display it when 500px and more, but hide it when less */
  .grid {grid-template-columns: 1fr}
  .grid .sidebar {display: none}
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works on a full-page layout, but not in a smaller container