# Using Logical Properties Inside Media Query Isn't Working

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to use [max-inline-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-inline-size) (the new logical properties) inside media query, but it doesn't seem to work.

The idea that in English it will be max-width:1000px; and in Japanese it will max-height:1000px

```
/*Not Working*/
@media (max-inline-size:1000px){
  .main-content{
    background:Red;
    grid-template-columns:auto;
  }
}
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/oQJmYQ/)

Comment: Is `max-inline-size` a feature of media?

Comment: its replacing of width/height depends the text block direction according to writing-mode property

Comment: ...this is a **highly** experimental property *not yet adopted by the CSSWG....it's still in Editor's Draft status

Comment: It's Supported almost in all browsers 
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-logical-props

Comment: @jned29: No, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

max-inline-size is not in the Media Features.

Use `max-height`    :The maximum height of the display area, such as a browser window
or `max-width`  :The maximum width of the display area, such as a browser window

Example:

```
@media (max-width:1000px){
  .main-content{
    background:Red;
    grid-template-columns:auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: The all Idea is that if will be dynamic, one time max-width and other time max-height. 
not good for me

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, logical properties are properties, not media features, and therefore cannot be used in a media query. Writing mode is a property of an element on a page, not the browser or media the page is being viewed on. You appear to be looking for an element query, which [doesn't exist in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen/12319280#12319280).