# Container query collapses width of element

Tags: html, css, container-queries

Why does `container-type: inline-size` render the span normally yet collapse the button:

```html
<span style="container-type: inline-size; outline: 1px solid blue;">
  This is a span
</span>

<button style="container-type: inline-size;">
  This is a button        
</button>
```

Comment: Adding `appearance: auto` to the span also breaks the width. But removing the style from the button doesn't fix the button.

Comment: I have found that it is related to `display: inline-block` if you create a div with these styles `<button style="display: inline-block; container-type: inline-size;">` you will get the same UI as the button. But applying `display: block` on the button doesn't fix the issue. Strange...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**tl;dr Containers can't be sized by their contents, and inline elements can't be containers.**

There are a few things going on here:

1. `container-type: inline-size` applies various [types of 'containment'](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-1/#containment-types) to the element, including `inline-size` containment.

   Size containment 'turns off' the ability for an element to get size information from its contents. That's important for container queries, since it breaks the 'infinite loop' where a container query changes the content size, which changes the query, which changes…

   So the container size has to come either from context (eg block elements stretch by default, elements in grid flex can also stretch, etc) or explicit sizing in CSS. Outside of those cases, elements with size containment will collapse. Since inline-block elements like buttons shrink-wrap to their contents, and size containment removes content-sizing, they collapse by default. Put them into a flex or grid, or add block display, and they'll stretch to fit their context.
2. Size containment doesn't work on inline elements (unless they are 'atomic inlines', eg images and videos and stuff without other content).

   Using an inline element as a container just isn't going to work. You can still use a span, just have to give it a non-inline display. This should be shown as a non-applied style in browser devtools, but I guess it isn't yet. I hope browsers clarify that.

So all your code is behaving according to spec. The fact that containers have to ignore their content size is the main reason we don't just *make everything a container*. It's also the trick that was required to make Container Queries work at all.

Answer (score 4):

> this answer it will show you some solutions with code,
>
>  But make sure to accept the @MiriamSuzanne answer for know the details of how/why this isn't working.

### final result (gif)

[image]

#### how to solve

for making this concept work:

1. you need a `<div>` as a container first.
2. then wrap the content you want inside, like a button or whatever.
3. and then give it to all elements Childs `width: 100%;` so now all children have the same @container width.

now you can have fun using `@container`

like this:

---

#### simple example

```css
.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.container>* {
  width: 100%;
}

.container button {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@container (width > 500px) {
  .container button {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>this is a button</button>
</div>
```

[image]

---

#### real world example

now I will prove that `@container` is different from `@media`

```css
.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.container,
.container>* {
  width: 100%;
}

.container button {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@container (width > 400px) {
  .container button {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- 1 item -->
<div class="container">
  <button>this is a button</button>
</div>

<!-- 2 items -->
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 4 items -->
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>this is a button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]