# CSS Container queries not working with flexbox space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox, container-queries

I want to add a CSS container query container for my 2nd child in my flexbox where both children are spaced out using `space-between` but it is not working. My second child goes off-screen and when I inspect the size of the `div.container` it says 0px width. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: #2b2e36;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background-color: green;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ffff0061;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ff000091;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>First</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div>Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kpx6gvn9/

[image]

Comment: container-type: inline-size; change it into this display: inline-size;

Comment: @Nisha what? no I want it to be a css container so I need `container-type`

Comment: @Pete sorry about that, updated the question.

Comment: Did you see in fiddle it's saying unbexpected unknown property

Comment: @Nisha that is because JSFiddle is not yet updated to the latest CSS spec. It is a valid property.

Comment: I guess `container-type: inline-size;` this is causing the undefined behaviour , try commenting this out and see if the problem still exists

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I know that much but I need to use CSS container queries that is why that property is there.

Comment: From https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-3/ section 3.1 this behaves exactly as intended: "Giving an element inline-size containment applies size containment to the inline-axis sizing of its principal box. This means the inline-axis intrinsic sizes of the principal box are determined as if the element had no content."

Comment: Check this related question and answer for an explanation of what's going on and why you have to specify a width on the container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975889/container-query-collapses-width-of-element/73980194#73980194

Answer (score 1):

Two important facts about container queries (from [Miriam Suzanne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975889/container-query-collapses-width-of-element/73980194#73980194), via [jerclarke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209859/jerclarke))

1. Containers can't be sized by their contents,
2. inline elements can't be containers.

No 1. This is the reason  I've run into problems with using `container-queries` inside flex.

For example: This [CodePen](https://%20https://codepen.io/dvdherron/pen/YzpywrZ) by [OddBird](https://www.oddbird.net/2021/04/05/containerqueries/) runs fine with the container inside grid:

```
.spread {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(50%, 1fr) minmax(min-content, 20em);
    gap: 2rem;
}
```

But when I fork it and change from grid to flex, it breaks in
firefox and chrome: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bjelline/pen/yLGJWzy)

```
.spread {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
}
```

To fix it, I had to add some sizing information to the section, for example with:

```
.spread section {
    flex: 1;
}
```

I found this solution in [Stephanie Eckles article](https://moderncss.dev/container-query-solutions-with-css-grid-and-flexbox/).

In your example, you have the same problem and the same solution will work: add sizing information to the two children of flexbox:

```css
body {
  background: #2b2e36;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ffff0061;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ff000091;
  flex: 1;
}

@container (max-width: 600px) {
    .container div {
          font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>First</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div>Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is documented somewhere, I'd love to see a link, reading over the MDN docs, I don't see any reference to this disruptive outcome of setting container-type on children of flex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type

Comment: Ok I found a good explanation of why the width on the container is needed: Check this related question and answer for an explanation of what's going on and why you have to specify a width on the container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975889/container-query-collapses-width-of-element/73980194#73980194