# Container Queries based on height not working

Tags: css, media-queries, container-queries

I would want to use the new CSS container queries in modern Safari/Chrome browser. (Safari 16.3, Google Chrome 113.0)

However container queries based on height are not working as expected.

Expected result: as soon as the outer container turns blue (500px screen height or below) I would expect the pink square (50vh of 500px container) to turn red.

Current result: The square stays pink and does not turn pink. The example works if the implementation is width relative.

**Did I do anything wrong in my implementation or is it just not jet implemented in Webkit engine? Any other solutions (without Javascript) to solve the problem, if in the final product the container will be resizeable by the user?**

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}

.container {
    height: 50vh;
    container-type: inline-size;
}

.test {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
            
@container (max-height: 250px) {
    .test {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
            
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    .container {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`inline-size` is the width not the height. You have to use `size`

> `inline-size`
>
> the query will be based on the inline dimensions of the container. Applies layout, style, and inline-size containment to the element. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries#using_container_queries)</sup>

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}

.container {
    height: 50vh;
    container-type: size;
}

.test {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
            
@container (max-height: 250px) {
    .test {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
            
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    .container {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also with container queries it's not sufficient to write only `min-height`

```css
.container {
  container-type: size;
  min-height: 50vh; /* doesn't work */
}
```

`height` has to be specified explicitly.

```css
.container {
  container-type: size;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Only then can you query the container

```css
@container (max-height: 200px) {
  .child {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Does that mean, we can't use container for elements with dynamic heights? For example I want to style a child of a textbox depending on the amount of text in it - e.g. make it smaller when there is a line break.
Alway when I set the container type to "size" all the heights of my Textbox seem to be reduced to zero - which results in all the sibling textboxes to overlap.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid that's the case. At least I could only get it to work when the height is specified explicitly on the reference container.

Comment: Doesn't this make height-based queries pointless? Since you already know the height of the thing you're querying because you have to set it explicitly?

Comment: Exactly. This behaviour indeed renders height-based container queries less useful for elements with dynamic content, because the very nature of dynamic content means that its dimensions aren't known until the content is rendered. 

I wonder if this is just a bug or bad API design.

Comment: Ok, this is by design to prevent infinite loops:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975889/container-query-collapses-width-of-element