# Trouble understanding containers, why does it work on my blog section but not on my article?

Tags: css, container-queries

I'm trying to understand properly the @container rules in CSS AND I don't get why my container work's on my `.blog-list` but not on my `article` ? I change the background of the article and it's perfectly fine in the `@container blog` and then I try to change the color of the text based on the size of the `article` in the `@container article`, but nothing is responding.

I have a pen to try out this [right here](https://codepen.io/margueronJanine/pen/BavLYKV?editors=0100)

```html
<div class="blog-list">
  <article>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Image">
    </figure>
    <div class="article-content">
    <h3><a href="#">Mon titre</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus erat neque, eu pulvinar justo efficitur et. Vivamus vel aliquam massa, rutrum sollicitudin ante. </p>
    <span class="link">En savoir plus</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Image">
    </figure>
    <div class="article-content">
    <h3><a href="#">Mon titre</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus erat neque, eu pulvinar justo efficitur et. Vivamus vel aliquam massa, rutrum sollicitudin ante. </p>
    <span class="link">En savoir plus</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Image">
    </figure>
    <div class="article-content">
    <h3><a href="#">Mon titre</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus erat neque, eu pulvinar justo efficitur et. Vivamus vel aliquam massa, rutrum sollicitudin ante. </p>
    <span class="link">En savoir plus</span>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

```css
.blog-list {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: blog;
}

article {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  container-name: article;
}

.article-content {
  padding: clamp(10px, 2.5vw, 2em) clamp(10px, 3vw, 2em);
  color: blue;
}

@container blog (max-width: 480px) {
  article {
    background: red;
  }
}

@container blog (min-width: 900px) {
  article {
    background: green;
  }
}

@container article (min-width: 200px) {
  .article-content {
    color: pink;
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

At first, I thought that perhaps only certain properties could be modified. It would have seemed strange to limit the possibilities, but at least I tried , and to no one's surprise, nothing changed.

Then I tried modifying the condition in `@container article (min-width: 200px)` in several different ways (width < 300px) or (max-width: 300px) and still nothing changes.

From what I understand, when I declare an `@container XY`, if the element on which I declare the `container-name: XY;` property matches the condition, it executes the different styles declared?

So what do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a problem with the container name. When I tried the following code:

```
@container (min-width: 200px) {
  .article-content {
    color: pink;
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

the color and background of *.article-content* is pink. But for using the syntax you provided, I added *container-type: inline-size;* to article:

```
article {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  container-name: article;
  container-type: inline-size; /* THIS LINE WAS ADDED */
}
```

The following code results in pink color and background when min-width of .article-content is 200px.

---

Comment: Thanks for the answers...this give me more question ! I tried to add the line...and when I put in `container-type: inline-size;`all of my content disapear...But the whole code work fine when I delete the name after `@container`...so I tell myself that I didn't really understand the meaning or the usefulness of the container-name... I will dig into this, but if you have tips & tricks where I could learn how to use properly those @container, please let me know :) !!!  Thanks a lot

Comment: container-name is just optional. A name can be provided which filters the set of query containers considered to just those with a matching query container name ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container)).--- and for container-type, the default value is "normal" which in that case, The element is not a query container for any container size queries.  ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type))

Comment: And that is why I added `container-type: inline-size;`

Comment: Tanks a lot, it makes much more sense now :) !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `container-type` declaration which is more important than the name. The name alone is useless. But if you make `article` containers, they will collapse because they can no more get sized by their content.

A gold rule when using a `@container`: never make an element whose content define its size a container. Flex items, inline-block, float, position: absolute/fixed, etc all of them cannot be container unless you explicitly define their width.

Related: [Container query collapses width of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975889/container-query-collapses-width-of-element)

Comment: Tanks for the explanations...I will dig deeper to fully understand the `container-type` and it's value :)