# Manually apply CSS breakpoint styles

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to chain css selectors with media queries, like:

```
.red,
@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

such that paragraphs will be red when the screen is <= 1000px OR when they inherit a `red` class?

The syntax above doesn't work, but there must be a dry way to do this. Maybe with `@extend`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one can do this with a mixin [[fiddle](https://codepen.io/duhaime/pen/KKRjoWy)]:

html:

```
<p>HI!</p>
<div><p>HO!</p></div>
```

css:

```
@mixin reddify {
  color: red;
}

div > p {
  @include reddify
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  html {
    @include reddify; 
  }
}
```

The `div > p` is always red, and the `p` will be red once the viewport is fewer than n pixels wide.